# Unity: Having Multiple BoxColliders with Unique Names?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to set up a system for a board game, and I want each cell of the board to have its own collider with a unique name which is formatted like:

> [column] + "  " + [row]

The issue I am having is that when I create a new collider, the name of all previous colliders change to the newest one's name.  The center of all of the colliders are different, so I am puzzled as to why the name changes and everything else stays the same.

```
private void Start()
{
    var offsetX = -3.5f;
    for (var x = 0; x < Board.Size; x++)
    {
        var offsetZ = -3.5f;
        for (var y = 0; y < Board.Size; y++)
        {
            var box = gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
            box.size = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
            box.center = new Vector3(offsetX, .5f, offsetZ);
            box.isTrigger = true;
            box.name = y + " " + x;
            offsetZ += 1f;
        }
        offsetX += 1f;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have each collider set with a unique name or is there a different way that is preferred to determine where on a game object a click occurred?

Comment: Where is the script above attached?

Comment: It is attach to the board itself

Comment: To each cell in the board? Do you have reference to each cell you want to attach the collider to?

Comment: The board is just one model, but I know where the cells are in relation to the center of the board.

Comment: What you set as name is the name of the GameObject the Collider is attached to. Question is, what do you need the name for? And actually, what do you need multiple Colliders for? Its a square board with 1 unit wide Cells. Attach just one Collider covering the whole Board and get the Cell by rounding the x and y component of the hit point to the nearest int (or if you align it in a smart way by simply casting them). Ofc this also works with different size Cells, it just requires a few divisions.

Answer (score 0):

Each MonoBehaviour has a life cycle method [OnCollisionEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html):

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    foreach (ContactPoint contact in collision.contacts)
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(contact.point, contact.normal, Color.white);
    }
}
```

Note the argument of this function, where you can find more information about the collider involved. You don't have to use name to identify the collider.

```
var collider = collision.collider;  //Here you get which collider is involved
var center = collider.bounds.center;
```